# PyQt6. Operator "-" not supported for types "QPoint" and "QPoint". Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)

Tags: pyqt, python-typing, pyqt6, pylance

```
self.move(qt_rectangle.topLeft() - QPoint(6, 0))
```

Is there any way to fix this error? I think it's the wrong type annotations in the PyQt6 framework for python, cause "+", "-" operands on QPoint are supported for sure.

Comment: Is this an *actual error* (meaning an exception thrown at runtime) or is it a warning from the IDE?

Comment: @musicamante It's a warning from IDE (VSCode)

Comment: Then it's probably a bug in the type hint files, doesn't affect execution. You can ignore it right now, possibly write a message to the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).